# HTML/JavaScript Debugging in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, internet-explorer-6

Running a webapplication in an environment with IE 6 (please do not comment that...), I'm looking for a debugging tool for html/javascript in Eclipse Galileo. I'm not supposed to install any other software but I'm able to install a Eclipse Plugin.

Thank you for every hint. :)

PS. IE 6 drives me nuts. I usually use FF or Chrome but sometimes its not my decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the ATF plugin for eclipse? Includes a JS debugger that looks and works similarly to the Java debugger.

Alternatively, you could use the MS Script Editor. It' ain't pretty, but it's got all the basic debugging support you probably need. Here's a link that does a decent job of explaining basic use and setup: http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer

My personal approach for using the MS debugger is to just insert a line into my code that says simply: `x.x;`
This will fire the debugger at exactly the spot I need, then I just change the value of x in the watchlist to be equal to `document`, thus correcting the error I forced. I can then step through the lines of my code and debug as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not have any permissions to change IE settings. Therefore your alternative hint won't work in our environment. ~~:-( However, I'll check the ATF Plugin. :-)

Comment: The ATF Plugin works fine in our environment. It's not that userfriendly than Firebug but ok. :-) Thank you again.

Comment: The ATF installer guide mentions that it uses Mozilla components. Does this mean that when you debug, you are debugging for a Firefox browser (versus IE, Chrome)? What if you have a Chrome-specific error you're trying to debug, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Link to ATF for previous post: http://www.eclipse.org/atf/